# Force user input in verbatim mode?

Tags: bash, user-input

I'm trying to any read user input keys in **verbatim** from Bash script, and then dump it into hex. That is:

```
read input
printf "%b" "$input" | xxd -p
```

If user press 2 keys <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, I would hope the output to be `617f`, not empty.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: So you want to stop the interpretation of all control characters (such as backspace, etc.)?

Comment: @AIG Yes, just for my purpose. I'm building an interactive tutorial asking things like "What do you press if you want to delete one word backwards from the command prompt", thus the question

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;do
    stty_state=$(stty -g) 
    #Save stty to reset to default
    stty raw isig -echo 
    #Set to raw and isig so nothing is interpretted and turn echo off so nothing is printed to screen.
    keypress=$(dd count=1 2>/dev/null)
    #Capture one character at a time
    #Redirect "errors" (from dd) output to dump
    keycode=$(printf "%s" "$keypress" | xxd -p)
    # Convert to hex
    stty "$stty_state"
    #Revert stty back
    printf "%s" "$keycode"
    #Print your key in hex
done
```

You can put a condition on the loop to exit the loop/program, otherwise you will need to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>` to exit.

This should print every key press except for <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>.

Comment: This does print most CTRL keys perfectly, like CTRL D,  CTRL L etc. It just respond to CTRL C by quitting the program