# Detecting key-press within Bash scripts

Tags: bash, keyboard

In the following code `INS=\x1b\x5b\x32\x7e` the hex value corresponds to **Insert** key.
Is it any list of hex values corresponding to key-press exists?

Comment: How did you get that code ?

Comment: @123 This is from "Advanced Bash Scripting" guide. Example 5-3. The code is successfully understands key-presses. That is what I'm wondering, where does this values come from?

Comment: You can look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340901/force-user-input-in-verbatim-mode/35341686#35341686) for a way to get the key codes in hex.

Answer (score 1):

Bash use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), so first notice that `\x` is not part of the key code, but used to tell that the following characters are an hexadecimal 1/2 digits code.

Let's look at `\x1b\x5b\x32\x7e` as example:

- `\x1b` is the [ASCII escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (`ESC`)
- `\x5b` refers to the character `[`. Used right after the escape code (so `ESC[`), it form with it a **Control Sequence Introducer** (CSI). A CSI tells to the terminal to interpret the next parameters as part of a sequence.

  This is used in the special cases of (not comprehensive):
   <kbd>INS</kbd>, <kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>⇱</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>.
  Why we need to use a CSI on those special keys? Because those keys use a **4 to 6 digits** hexadecimal code - so it can't be interpreted with a single `\x00` parameter, it must be a sequence.
- `\x32` and `\x7e` together are the control sequence, which basically is translated to `2~` which refer to the <kbd>INS</kbd> command. In the [ANSI standard for ASCII terminals](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/ansicode.txt), the keys listed before are identified by a combination of a decimal code and the `~` (`\x7e`) character. In a CSI sequence, the action is defined by the last character - in this case `~` which correspond to the "special keys action".

Let's get an other example to prove this: `17~` means <kbd>F6</kbd> , and is translated to `\x31\x37\x7e` using [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
HEX  Chr
---  ---
31   1
37   7
7E   ~
```

So, that looks good - we have `\x1b\x5b\x31\x37\x7e` when adding the CSI, which is the valid code in bash for <kbd>F6</kbd> - see [this gist](https://github.com/robhagemans/pcbasic/blob/master/pcbasic/ansi.py) that list most of the special keys code.

But how to know that <kbd>F6</kbd> should be translated to `17~`? By looking at the [ANSI code table](http://www.real-world-systems.com/docs/ANSIcode.html), you will find the following:

> `176` `7E` `~`  `DECKEYS`   Sent by special function keys
>
> `[1~=FIND, [2~=INSERT, [3~=REMOVE, [4~=SELECT, [5~=PREV, [6~=NEXT
>   [11~=F1… [17~=F6…[34~=F20 ([23~=ESC,[24~=BS,[25~=LF,[28~=HELP,[29~=DO)`

This isn't perfect, but from this you can establish the following table (***this is theoretical***, probably need some validation):

```
+-----+------+-------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| Key | Code |     Hex     |    Key    |    Code    |        Hex        |
+-----+------+-------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| F6  | [17~ | 5B 31 37 7E | END       | [4~ OR [OF | 5B 34 7E OR 4F 46 |
| F7  | [18~ | 5B 31 38 7E | Home (⇱)  | [1~ OR [OH | 5B 31 7E OR 4F 48 |
| F8  | [19~ | 5B 31 39 7E | Page down | [6~        | 5B 36 7E          |
| F9  | [20~ | 5B 32 30 7E | Page up   | [5~        | 5B 35 7E          |
| F10 | [21~ | 5B 32 31 7E | Up        | [!         | 5B 41             |
| F11 | [23~ | 5B 32 33 7E | Down      | ["         | 5B 42             |
| F12 | [24~ | 5B 32 34 7E | Right     | [#         | 5B 43             |
| INS | [2~  | 5B 32 7E    | Left      | [$         | 5B 44             |
| DEL | [3~  | 5B 33 7E    |           |            |                   |
+-----+------+-------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
```

Which should be enough for most of your uses.

*Please note that this answer is an attempt to explain the ANSI quoting for keys in bash, it might not be accurate because of the lack of documentation about this.*